'TranscriptionConsumer' object has no attribute 'base_send' Websocket Django
I'm trying to do site that translates .wav audio into text in django. I've got a problem here. I'm using websocket to send translated text immediately. But when I try to send a text, this error occurs ('TranscriptionConsumer' object has no attribute 'base_send')
views.py
# this function recognites text and send it to Consumers's function
def get_large_audio_transcription(path,language, consumer ,minutes=2):
    sound = AudioSegment.from_file(path)
    
    chunk_length_ms = int(1000*60*minutes)
    
    chunks = [sound[i:i + chunk_length_ms] for i in range(0, len(sound), chunk_length_ms)]
    
    folder_name=str(settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + "/audio-chunks/"
    
    if not os.path.isdir(folder_name):
        os.mkdir(folder_name)
        
    whole_text = ""
    
    for i, audio_chunk in enumerate(chunks,start=1):
        chunk_filename = os.path.join(folder_name, f"chunk{i}.wav")
        audio_chunk.export(chunk_filename, format="wav")
        
        try:
            text = transcribe_small_audio(chunk_filename, language=language)
            
        except sr.UnknownValueError as e:
            print("Error:", str(e))
        else:
            text = f"{text.capitalize()}."
            print(text)
            whole_text += text
            json_transcribe = json.dumps({"message": text})
            # Sending json text through WebSocket
            consumer.send_json(json_transcribe)
            # deleting chunk
            try:
                os.remove(chunk_filename)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print("Error: file not found")
    return whole_text



@login_required(login_url='login_user')
def index(request):
    context = None
    audio_form = UploadFileForm()
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        audio_form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        
        if not audio_form.is_valid():
            messages.success(request, ("Error!"))
            return render(request, 'recognition/index.html', {"error": "Provide a valid file"})
        
        try:
            form = audio_form.save(commit=False)
            form.name = request.user
            form.save()
            
            
            file = form.audio # get the audio 
            file_size = file.size
            file_path = str(settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + '/' + str(file.name)
      
            consumer = TranscriptionConsumer()
            messages.success(request, ("File size is too big. We will give you a file with transcription..."))
            text = get_large_audio_transcription(file_path,"en-US", consumer)
            
            os.remove(file_path)
            
            context = {
                "text" :text,
                "AudioForm":audio_form,
                "size" : file_size
                }
            
        except Exception as ex:
            context = {"error": str(ex)}
    else:
        context = {
            "AudioForm" : audio_form 
        }
    return render(request, "recognition/index.html", context )

My consumers.py
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer

class TranscriptionConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()
    
    def send_json(self, text_data):
        self.connect()
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        text_message = text_data_json["message"]
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message' : text_message
        }))

index.html file
{% extends 'app/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<h2>Upload file</h2>

<form method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ AudioForm | crispy }}
    <div class="d-grid gap-3 mt-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Upload audio</button>
    </div>
</form>
    
<p>Your file size :</p>
{{ size|filesizeformat }}
{{ size }}
<h2>Transcript</h2>

{% if error %}
    <p id="error" style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
{% endif %}
<p id="app">
    
    {{ text }}

</p>

<script>
    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws/somepath/');

    socket.onmessage = function (event) {
        const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log(data.message);
        document.querySelector('#app').innerText = data.message
    };
</script>
{% endblock %}

I expect recognized text to appear on the page, instead I get an error.
Btw I'm new to django

I noticed a few things in your code that might be causing issues. For example, calling self.connect() in send_json isn't necessary—Django Channels automatically calls connect() when a WebSocket connection is established, so you don’t need to call it again in send_json.
Also, in send_json, you can use self.send directly to send JSON data to the WebSocket client.
Here’s an updated version of your TranscriptionConsumer class and the get_large_audio_transcription function that should work:
# consumers.py

import json
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer

class TranscriptionConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()
    
    def send_json(self, text_data):
        # Send text data as JSON to the WebSocket
        self.send(text_data)

And for the get_large_audio_transcription function:
# This function recognizes text and sends it to the Consumer's function
def get_large_audio_transcription(path, language, consumer, minutes=2):
    sound = AudioSegment.from_file(path)
    chunk_length_ms = int(1000 * 60 * minutes)
    chunks = [sound[i:i + chunk_length_ms] for i in range(0, len(sound), chunk_length_ms)]
    folder_name = str(settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + "/audio-chunks/"
    
    if not os.path.isdir(folder_name):
        os.mkdir(folder_name)
        
    whole_text = ""
    
    for i, audio_chunk in enumerate(chunks, start=1):
        chunk_filename = os.path.join(folder_name, f"chunk{i}.wav")
        audio_chunk.export(chunk_filename, format="wav")
        
        try:
            text = transcribe_small_audio(chunk_filename, language=language)
        except sr.UnknownValueError as e:
            print("Error:", str(e))
        else:
            text = f"{text.capitalize()}."
            print(text)
            whole_text += text
            json_transcribe = json.dumps({"message": text})
            # Sending JSON text through WebSocket
            consumer.send_json(json_transcribe)
            
            # Deleting chunk
            try:
                os.remove(chunk_filename)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print("Error: file not found")
    
    return whole_text

